# Bash script to run "pecl install oci8"

Tags: ubuntu, bash, shell-script, make, pecl

I am trying to create shell script that will do the initial provisioning of a vagrant vm (running Ubuntu 12.04). Everything (installing php, apache, oracle instantclient, etc,) works fine, except for the last step - installing the php oci8 extension:

```
pecl install oci8
```

When I run this command manually (with sudo prefix) it works fine. But when the script runs this command it fails like this:

```
running: make
/bin/bash /tmp/pear/temp/pear-build-rootG74SsU/oci8-2.0.6/libtool --mode=compile cc  -I. -I/tmp/pear/temp/oci8 -DPHP_ATOM_INC -I/tmp/pear/temp/pear-build-rootG74SsU/oci8-2.0.6/include -I/tmp/pear/temp/pear-build-rootG74SsU/oci8-2.0.6/main -I/tmp/pear/temp/oci8 -I/usr/include/php5 -I/usr/include/php5/main -I/usr/include/php5/TSRM -I/usr/include/php5/Zend -I/usr/include/php5/ext -I/usr/include/php5/ext/date/lib -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64  -DHAVE_CONFIG_H  -g -O2   -c /tmp/pear/temp/oci8/oci8.c -o oci8.lo
libtool: compile:  cc -I. -I/tmp/pear/temp/oci8 -DPHP_ATOM_INC -I/tmp/pear/temp/pear-build-rootG74SsU/oci8-2.0.6/include -I/tmp/pear/temp/pear-build-rootG74SsU/oci8-2.0.6/main -I/tmp/pear/temp/oci8 -I/usr/include/php5 -I/usr/include/php5/main -I/usr/include/php5/TSRM -I/usr/include/php5/Zend -I/usr/include/php5/ext -I/usr/include/php5/ext/date/lib -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -g -O2 -c /tmp/pear/temp/oci8/oci8.c  -fPIC -DPIC -o .libs/oci8.o
In file included from /tmp/pear/temp/oci8/oci8.c:48:0:
/tmp/pear/temp/oci8/php_oci8_int.h:60:17: fatal error: oci.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
make: *** [oci8.lo] Error 1
ERROR: `make' failed
```

The `pecl` script asks for a path in the beginning of the installation, and this is where I think the issue is:

```
Please provide the path to the ORACLE_HOME directory. Use 'instantclient,/path/to/instant/client/lib' if you're compiling with Oracle Instant Client [autodetect] :
```

For the installation to proceed you either need to supply the ORACLE_HOME directory or press <kbd>Enter</kbd>. I have tried the following suggested elsewhere, but it does not work - the line break is missing in the output (compared to when running the `pecl` command manually) so it does not properly emulate the <kbd>Enter</kbd> keystroke:

```
printf "\n" | pecl install oci8
```

Any suggestions on how I can get this to run properly?

Comment: Could you try `echo autodetect | pecl install oci8`?

Comment: @gnp I tried that, and also `printf "autodetect"`, didn't help.

Answer (score 2):

My solution was to run the following command:

```
export C_INCLUDE_PATH=/usr/include/oracle/11.2/client
```

and restart:

```
pecl insatlla oci8
```

Answer (score 1):

I did not really find a general purpose solution to this problem. What ended up working in my specific scenario (provisioning via Vagrant) was using a Puppet manifest for this specific provisioning step, which was easy since you just need to specify it in the Vagrant configuration after the Shell provisioner:

```
"pecl-install-oci8":
    command => "pecl install oci8",
    user => root,
    timeout => 0,
    tries   => 5,
    unless => "/usr/bin/php -m | grep -c oci8";
```

For some reason that I have yet to figure out, puppet installs oci8 without issue.

And when I'd done this I ported my whole script to a Puppet manifest, but that is off-topic.

Answer (score 1):

Typically for this kind of installation you can echo in the parameters you want to set. I wrapped the entire statement so that it can be executed with sudo permissions

```
sudo sh -c "echo 'instantclient,/opt/oracle/instantclient' | pecl install oci8"
```